# Tableau python API ssl certificate verify false

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am using the following code to create tableau connection. Tableau server using signed certifcates.

https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/set_http_options.py

```
    server.add_http_options({'verify': False})
```

The codes works fine with verify = False, but that doesn't sound like a ideal thing in production environment. It didn't worked fine with the above line of code. I want to use the proper verification for any operation.

I tried googling out the problem but couldn't really found that.

Comment: Why are you using that argument in the first place, though?

Comment: It didn't work without that and gave ssl cert errors

Comment: what is the server url you were using? is it a https? if so, can you try the whole code with http instead? this made the trick for me :)